# How to read files as hex

Tags: javascript, python, hex

I want to to be able to be given an input file with any sort of extension and read it in as hex or binary, but in a string or something. Not like `open(file_path, 'rb')` in python. Preferably in python or JS.

Comment: What's the issue with open(file_path, "rb")?? You can access all the bytes using indexing and even change them?

Comment: @OmOWalker It doesn't let me loop through each one individually. or it does and I am unaware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can use print() with "x" format to format a byte as 2-digit hex string. Use 'rb' file mode to open file in binary mode to process file stream as a sequence of bytes. You can read a block of data at a time then iterate over each block one byte at a time.

```python
import sys

with open(sys.argv[1], 'rb') as fin:
    while True:
        data = fin.read(16)
        if len(data) == 0:
            break
        # iterate over each byte in byte sequence
        for b in data:
            print(' {:02x}'.format(b), end='')
        print()
```

If run code above on the source code then output would be a sequence of 16 hex numbers on each line.

**Output:**

```
69 6d 70 6f 72 74 20 73 79 73 0d 0a 0d 0a 77 69
74 68 20 6f 70 65 6e 28 73 79 73 2e 61 72 67 76
...
3d 27 27 29 0d 0a 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 70 72
69 6e 74 28 29 0d 0a
```

For example, the first line "import sys" is output as `69 6d 70 6f 72 74 20 73 79 73` followed by `0d 0a` for CR LF characters.